# Arima NM46X installing ESXi 'Unsupported microcode level 0x01000039'

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have an Arima NM46X dual Opteron server that I am attempting to install ESXi 5.1 on.  During the loading of the installer, I am receiving the below message:

```
VMware ESXi 5.1.0 (WMKernel Release Build 799733)

The system has found a problem on your machine and cannot continue.
Unsupported microcode level 0x01000039
Please use microcode patch level 0x01000065 or higher with
AMD Family 10h B3 processors.
```

Arima appears to be out of business, and BIOS on their website for this machine is v1.08.  The server is currently running v1.10.

Has anyone run into this issue or have any suggestions?

Many thanks!

Comment: Does the hardware appear on the Hardware Compatibly List? Regardless, it sounds like you're out of luck. You could try older versions, but I doubt it.

Comment: @Dan - Unfortunately it is not on the HCL.  I was hoping to use this machine to test before purchasing new servers.  I found this link after two days of digging on the web: http://vmwise.com/2010/06/03/things-i-want-to-remember/.  I'm going to give it a try. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone that runs into the Microcode error on a ESX/i install, below are the steps that I took.

When launching the installer for ESXi 5.1, I entered shift+o and added attribute 'skipMicrocodeCompatCheck'.

Once installed, when vmware is booting, shift+o again and enter attribute 'skipMicrocodeCompatCheck'.

After installation, SSH to the Host machine and run command 'esxcfg-advcfg -k TRUE skipmicrocodecompatcheck'

Note that this should only be done on test or lab machines and not production environments, as systems that do not pass CompatCheck are not supported by VMware.

Source: http://vmwise.com/2010/06/03/things-i-want-to-remember/

Secondary Source (may take some time to load): http://communities.vmware.com/thread/236107?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score -1):

After install  click:- shift o, while it's booting up.
then type:- skipMicrocodeCompatCheck
At the menu hit F2 and select troubleshooting options
Enable ESXi shell
ALT F1, and put your username and password in or just type:- root and hit enter, if you haven't already set the password up.
type:- esxcfg-advcfg -k TRUE skipmicrocodecompatcheck
Then check that the change has been made using vi, type:- vi /etc/vmware/esx.conf   look for this line in the file:-

```
/vmkernel/skipMicrocodeCompatCheck = "TRUE"
```

If it is great, now we have to save the change from memory to disk, run:-

```
/sbin/auto-backup.sh /etc/vmware/esx.conf
```

then reboot (the machine will reboot eventually and no more entering the skipmicrocodecompatcheck at bootup.

reference [this article](http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2011/08/how-to-persist-configuration-changes-in.html) on how the esxi shell operates:-

So why does editing files in ESXi filesystem not persisted across system reboots? The reason for this is ESXi uses an in-memory filesystem. For more details, check out The

Architecture of VMware ESXi whitepaper by VMware. As I mentioned earlier, the persistence of files will depend on what was updated as there are exceptions to the rules.